# PushButton not animating in Qt4

Tags: python, pyqt

I am a newbie to this forum as well as to Python and PyQt.
After going through a few basics, in my attempt to learn animation using Qt, I wished to write a simple application where a PushButton is animatedly brought from the left of the screen to a certain position on the click of another button. In the process, I ended up writing code like this:

```
class AppMainUI(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

    self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Window|QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    self.connect(self.pushButton_4, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onExitClicked)
    self.connect(self.pushButton_5, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.animateButtons)

    def animateButtons(self):
        animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.pushButton, "geometry")
        animation.setDuration(2)
        animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, self.pushButton.width(), self.pushButton.height()))
        animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(760, 280, self.pushButton.width(), self.pushButton.height()))
        animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.OutElastic)
        animation.start()

    def onExitClicked(self):
        sys.exit(0)

App = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
UI = AppMainUI()
UI.show()
App.exec_()
```

What I see is that the button moves to the position (0, 0) which is actually my start position for the animation. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to *Garbage collector*; when the method `animateButtons(self)` is finished with the `animation.start()` statement the `animation` object is destroyed by the *Garbage collector*, thus the animation does not take place.

Just add `self` at the start of your object name:

```
self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(...)
self.animation.setStartValue(...)
...
```

Also increase the duration to at least 1000 ms, so that animation become visible, otherwise it will be executed so fast that you would not be able to see it.